# Remote Desktop Web Feed pointing to specific servers in farm

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, remoteapp

I have a Remote Desktop Session Host farm with a Remote Desktop Connection Broker (Server 2008 R2) arbitrating connections for this farm. The Connection Broker is configured as the RD Web Access RemoteApp source (with the Web Access role installed on the same machine):

[image: RD Web Access Configuration]

and Windows 7 clients are connecting to the RD Web feed to receive the RemoteApp connection files. Everything works so far except for one major detail - the RDP files received from the RD Web Access server are directing users to a ***specific session host*** in the farm (the first one joined) instead of the farm itself, thus introducing a single point of failure and defeating the load balancing capabilities of a farm.

I obviously could enter the RD farm name as the "Source name" instead of the connection broker's, but since the RD connection broker is aggregating a number of farms and single RD servers and I would like to keep a single point of administration, I would rather not do this.

So can I change this behavior by reconfiguration or a hotfix? Would upgrading to a Server 2012 R2 connection broker help matters here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a configuration oversight. While the RD connection broker is using the defined servers as RemoteApp sources, it exercises no control over the actual *definitions* of RemoteApp items provided by them. The RemoteApp Manager configuration of the respective RemoteApp sources is determining what destination RemoteApp clients will connect to:

[image: RemoteApp Manager]

*This option needs to point to the farm's name on **all** of your farm session hosts.* If even one of the hosts has this setting pointing to its own host name (as is the default configuration after enabling the Remote Desktop Role), you might end up with the connection broker handing out these host-specific RDP files.